# Check Spark Dataframe row has ANY column meeting a condition and stop when first such column found

Tags: apache-spark

The following code can be used to filter rows that contain a value of 1. Image there are a lot of columns.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType

val df = sc.parallelize(Seq(
   ("r1", 1, 1),
   ("r2", 6, 4),
   ("r3", 4, 1),
   ("r4", 1, 2)
   )).toDF("ID", "a", "b")

val ones = df.schema.map(c => c.name).drop(1).map(x => when(col(x) === 1, 1).otherwise(0)).reduce(_ + _)

df.withColumn("ones", ones).where($"ones" === 0).show
```

The downside here is that it should ideally stop when the first such condition is met. I.e. the first column found. OK, we all know that.

But I cannot find an elegant method to achieve this without presumably using a UDF or very specific logic. The map will process all cols.

Can therefore a fold(Left) be used that can terminate when first occurrence found possibly? Or some other approach? May be an oversight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first idea was to use logical expressions and hope for short-circuiting, but it seems spark is not doing this :

```
df
  .withColumn("ones", df.columns.tail.map(x => when(col(x) === 1, true)
  .otherwise(false)).reduceLeft(_ or _))
  .where(!$"ones")
  .show()
```

But I'm no sure whether spark does support short-circuiting, I think not (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-18712)

So alternatively you can apply a custom function on your rows using lazy `exist` on scala's `Seq`:

```
df
  .map{r => (r.getString(0),r.toSeq.tail.exists(c => c.asInstanceOf[Int]==1))}
  .toDF("ID","ones")
  .show()
```

This approach is similar to an UDF, so not sure if thats what you accept.

Comment: Will try tonight. Looks interesting.

Comment: I cannot follow the first example 1) it goes through all columns I am assuming 2) I have never seen reduceLeft(_ or _)) - the or that is 3) reduce or reduceRight also work. Interesting stuff, the following does not work val b = Array(true, false, true, false)
b.reduceLeft(_ or _).

Comment: @thebluephantom `reduceLeft` goes from left to right, `reduce` does not apply a specific order.For pure scala booleans you cannot use `or` because this is a method defined on `Column`, you would do instead : `Array(true,false,true).reduceLeft(_ || _)`

Comment: Sorry, revise my comment: I think you loop through all columns applying a boolean if (true/false or true/false.  I will try and see if and works as well, technically. Leansome, awesome. But the solution must iterate through all columns. thx. Indeed the and does, gotcha.

Comment: On the second example, my impression is that the exists will stop as soon as first match is found. If that is the case, then this is the idea I was looking for. I remember a post  of yours on exist somewhere in the past. The toSeq means that all cols need to be Seq(ed) but that is small beer. Anyway, assuming this is what I think, I am glad of this all.